# How to retrieve URL from email using AppleScript?

Tags: url, curl, applescript, extract

I've done this in the past but for this particular example, the URL is not evident:
I have an email that arrives inviting the recipient to click on a link. If I hover over the link, I see the URL,

[image]

and, of course, if I click it, it opens on the browser, as expected. In the past, I would extract the contents of the email with AppleScript and the body of the message would show the URL.

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
```

use scripting additions

set theMsg to MailLib's ExtractEmailMessages()
set theMsg to item 1 of theMsg
tell application "Mail"
set BodyMessage to content of theMsg
end tell

But this time BodyMessage only shows text and no URL. It only shows this:

> 

Comments from the client (if any):
Are you available to take this order?

Please note: If you click YES, the order will be AUTOMATICALLY assigned to you.  Please contact the client after.

YES, I WILL TAKE THIS ORDER
￼

Is there a way to extract the URL, so that I can open the link with AppleScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Mail.app dictionary

- The `content` property  contains the plain text.
- The `source` property contains all headers and the HTML text.

You have to extract the HTML text beginning with `<html>` or `<!DOCTYPE` from the `source` and use an HTML parser or `text item delimiters` to extract the information.